# factory girl with faker generate same data in node express

Tags: node.js, factory-bot, faker

I am trying to have factory girl generate test data:

```js
import { factory } from "factory-girl";
import faker from "faker";

export const adminDef = (factory: Static) =>
  factory.define('User', User, {
    email: internet.email(),
    password: internet.password(),
    firstName: name.firstName(),
    lastName: name.lastName(),
    phoneNumber: phone.phoneNumber(),
    role: UserRole.ADMIN
  });
```

The problem I am having is every time I call `factory.create("User")` twice. It tries to create the same `user` data. Instead of creating different objects. In rails, you can just wrap faker with `{ }`. How do I do that in node?

Comment: what is your definition for your factory attributes? Like `internet.email()` what is its implementation? Generally, I would recommend using faker - https://www.npmjs.com/package/Faker to generate fake data in NodeJS.

Comment: that is using faker. I just imported internet from faker, instead of importing `faker` as whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the definition as a function, it worked! Not sure where to find this in the doc.

```
export const adminDef = (factory: Static) =>
  factory.define('User', User, () => ({
    email: internet.email(),
    password: internet.password(),
    firstName: name.firstName(),
    lastName: name.lastName(),
    phoneNumber: phone.phoneNumber(),
    role: UserRole.ADMIN
  }));
```

Comment: @PruthviKumar No, the 3rd argument to `factory.define` is a function instead of an object

Comment: Very clever, dude. 101%